# Force willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, orientation, autorotate

I want to call willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method when my app starts, how can I force this method toe execute?
It's only invoked when I rotate device now :(

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{    
    return YES;
}
```

One detail... when device is in horizontal mode it is called but when I start with device in vertical mode this method is never invoked :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set your orientation to UISupportedInterfaceOrientations in the Info.plist file?